# html javascript change content

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Hey guys I am trying to change content of a div with javascript for educational purposes (helping someone with a college project). This is what I got so far -

```
<div id="navbar">
  ...
  <ul>
    <li> <text onclick="getWordProcessing()"> Word Processing</text></li>
  </ul>
  ...
</div>

<div id="content"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getWordProcessing(){
      document.getElementById("content").textContent=
         "--something for word processing--";
    }
  </script>
```

When clicking on the text in the list, the content div changes like Id expect but changes back to being empty right away as if the page was refreshed. Howcome? This is very demoralizing.

Thank you for your time.

The above issue has been resolved, however I just discovered something else here -

http://jsfiddle.net/joseramonc/7XvZx/

```
    <ol start="1">
    <h3> CST Learning Outcomes</h3>
    <li> <text onclick="getWordProcessing()"> Word Processing</text></li>
    <li> <a href="" onclick="getWordProcessing()"> Word Processing</a></li>
    </ol>
```

Using the text works like expected while the link does not.

Comment: I just have. Results are identical.

Comment: @user121987 Try to not use a self closing div-tag.

Comment: because innerHTML is the correct property, also there is no tag <text> and you can't close divs like you do

Comment: Also, use `<div id="content"></div>`  instead of `<div id="content" />`.  Modern browsers won't recognize it as closed.

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is also valid. And if it is pure text without tags that is changed, there is no need to use `innerHTML`. Is is actually discouraged to do so.

Comment: @user1219387 With your `<a href="" onclick=...>` you are actually making a relative link to the current page with your empty string in `href=""`. Since you aren't preventing the default action in your click-handler, the browser will first execute your click-handler, then redirect you to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getWordProcessing(){
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=
            "--something for word processing--";
}
```

Comment: Just did. Now in Firefox clicking the text produces absolutely no effect, in Opera there is no difference with original issue, and in IE it opens the root (local) directory of the site.

Comment: Try it with innerHTML!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this jsFiddle i just did, it works. just declared the function before. The problem is that you have to define your `function getWordProcessing` before calling it.

http://jsfiddle.net/joseramonc/7XvZx/3/

Comment: `innerText` is for versions of Internet explorer before 9. Other browsers (and IE from version 9) use `textContent`.

Comment: You are correct. However, how come

        <li> <text onclick="getWordProcessing()"> Word Processing</text></li>
has permanent effect like Id imagine it to work, while

        <li> <a href="" onclick="getWordProcessing()"> Word Processing</a></li>
changes the div momentarily and changes it back?

Comment: @user1219387 you'd like to have the text just for a moment and then return to your old text?

Comment: @user1219387 With your `<a href="" onclick=...>` you are actually making a relative link to the current page `href=""`. Since you aren't preventing the default action in your click-handler, the browser will redirect you to the current page.

Comment: No, I am trying to change it permanently. I see what you are saying, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to fix the HTML, instead of `<div id="content"/>` put `<div id="content"></div>`

Then replace `innerText` with `innerHTML`

```
<script>
    function getWordProcessing(){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "--something for word processing--";
    }
</script>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <text onclick="getWordProcessing()"> Word Processing</text>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joseramonc/7XvZx/

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that when you change content of an html element like as a DIV from javascript, its content will not persist after refreshing the page. But you can use an input control like as a TextBox to keep the value even after refresh. I test this and it works fine:

```
<div id="navbar">
    ...
    <ul>
    <li> <text onclick="getWordProcessing()"> Word Processing</text></li>
    </ul>
    ...
</div>

<input type="text" id="content" readonly="readonly" style="border:none; width:100%;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function getWordProcessing()
{
        document.getElementById("content").value = "--something for word processing--";
}
</script>
```

The textbox border is set to none and it is readonly to be like as a normal text content.
if you want a multiple line message, you must use a `textarea` element instead of `input type="text"` as your content placeholder.

Comment: did you test this? is it OK or you have any problem?